# Добавление столбца в oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Стоит задача добавить столбец в таблицу oracle после определенного столба. Пробовал так: `ALTER TABLE <имя таблицы> ADD <имя столца> VARCHAR(255) AFTER <имя столбца после которого необходимо добавить>`;
Но данный способ не отрабатывает

Comment: а зачем? я надеюсь вы не используете в приложениях `SELECT *`?

Comment: какая версия Oracle?

Comment: Использую Oracle 10g

Comment: в 10g нету такой возможности, появилось только 12с! Разве что можно придумать какой то велосипед!

Comment: @MaxU Зачем? Ну есть ещё, например, такой фактор как - технический руководитель проекта с повышенным уровнем перфекционизма.

Comment: @0xdb, да я сам был таким лет 10-15 назад. :)  Позже когда повозился с `dbms_redefinition` на больших таблицах исключительно по причине приступа нездорового перфектионизма  понял что оно того не стоит... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в Oracle 12c: это пример

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER_DATA (
  CD_ID          INTEGER,
  CUST_NUMBER_ID INTEGER,
  FIRST_NAME     NVARCHAR2(30),
  LAST_NAME      NVARCHAR2(30),
  FLAG           NVARCHAR2(10),
  CUST_ACTIVE    INTEGER
);

ALTER TABLE CUSTOMER_DATA ADD (FULL_NAME VARCHAR (50) NULL);

ALTER TABLE CUSTOMER_DATA MODIFY (FLAG INVISIBLE, CUST_ACTIVE INVISIBLE);

ALTER TABLE CUSTOMER_DATA MODIFY (FLAG VISIBLE, CUST_ACTIVE VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 2):

Порядок столбцов в таблице в нормальном случае не должен играть ни какой роли.
То есть, если стоит такая задача, то ранее были допущены ошибки в дизайне БД или использующих её приложений.
Если бы порядок столбцов был бы важен и нужен, то оператор `AFTER` уже скорее всего был бы реализован в стандарте SQL.

Если всё-таки в редких случаях порядок столбцов желателен, например, для генераторов кода, то самое простое использовать представление вместо физической таблицы.
Изменение порядка столбцов в представлении не затрагивает структуры физической таблицы (*indexes, constraints, triggers* и пр.), то есть по-сути пройдёт "безболезнено":

```
create table itemstab (id number, name varchar2 (32), changed timestamp);
-- возникла необходимость добавить столбец
alter table itemstab add (memo varchar2 (64));
create or replace view items as 
    select id, name, memo, changed from itemstab;

insert into items values (1, 'item 1', 'memo 1', systimestamp); 

select rowid, i.* from items i;

ROWID                      ID NAME       MEMO       CHANGED                     
------------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- -----------------------------
AAAS+TAAQAAAFrHAAA          1 item 1     memo 1     2018-10-06 12:59:57,373961000
```

И только в крайнем случае, можно воспользоваться многочисленными решениями, например, [в этой ветке на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391280/how-to-insert-a-column-in-a-specific-position-in-oracle-without-dropping-and-rec). Самый, по-моему мнению, правильный путь там отсутствует - выгрузить данные, пересоздать таблицу с "нуля", залить сохранённые данные.

В 12c появилась возможность изменить порядок столбцов изменением видимости уже существующих столбцов. Но основная цель введения невидимых столбцов - упростить миграцию старых, зависимых от порядка столбцов, приложений. Поэтому, этот способ добавить столбец в середину, иначе как "злоупотребленим" назвать нельзя - "от чего пытались уйти, туда и пришли".  Подробнее в [блоге Тома Кайта](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/on-oracle-database-12c%2c-part-5).

Answer (score 1):

1. Непонятно, почему вы решили, что это должно работать. В [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_3001.htm) такого нет. Ни по вашей версии, ни по какой-либо другой.
2. Этого и не должно там быть, и работать так тоже не обязано. В SQL вообще нет такого понятия, как "порядок столбцов" (порядка строк тоже нет, кстати). В принципе, за "порядок" можно принять порядок, в котором они перечисляются в процессе создания, или порядок, в котором они выводятся в запросе `select * from ...`, но это "неофициально".
3. Есть только один порядок - тот, который вы задаете явно, перечислив поля в операторах `INSERT`, `SELECT`, `MERGE` и т. д. Вот этот порядок гарантированно соблюдается СУБД.

**UPD** . 
Не, с порядком столбцов я немного поспешил, кусок ответа выше вырезан. В реляционной теории порядок не нужен, но Oracle, тем не менее, все-таки его немного [поддерживает](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm):

> **table.* | view.* | materialized view.***
>
> Specify the object name followed by a period and the asterisk to select all columns from the specified table, view, or materialized view. Oracle Database returns a set of columns in the order in which the columns were specified when the object was created.